# How to convert screen co-ordinates into 2D OpenGL co-ordinates

Tags: ios, math, opengl-es, geometry

I have the following 2D orthographic projection set up on my iPad:

- Origin in the centre of the display
- (+1,+1) in the upper right corner
- (-1,-1) in the lower right corner
- This is adjusted to the iPad's 1.333 aspect ratio so X runs from -1.33 to +1.33

The iPad is landscape with its button on the left with screen co-ords like this:

- Origin at lower right corner
- (1024,768) at upper left corner

How do I calculate the 2D GL position when the user touches the screen? iOS gives me the screen location where the user tapped.

I.e if I tap the screen in the middle, iOS tells me I tapped at (512,384) so this should be converted to (0,0), (1024,768) to (-1.33,1.0) etc.

I know this should be a reasonably straight forward bit of maths, but my brain's gone to mush after trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a screen with dimensions *w* and *h*, mapping to [-1, -1]...[1, 1] goes like this:

```
X = 2*x/w - 1
Y = 1 - 2*y/h
```

To match the aspect ratio of the screen, multiply X by w/h.

Comment: Piku made a bit of a mess in his question. His x GL coordinates are [-1.33, 133], so edit X by multiplying it by aspect ratio (1.33).

Comment: @MaticOblak: On a 1024x768 screen, w/h is approximately 1.33.